# Apollo gradient rear bottom frame mount pivot point

Tags: mountain-bike

After only 6 months of use the bottom pivot point has developed play where the rear frame section is rocking from side to side I have looked everywhere for what is causing the problem and for the replacement parts to fix this problem with no success your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Apollo brand seems to be a cheap walmart-style BSO - can you please add a photo with [edit]  or a link to a website of this bike ?

Comment: Do you ride it hard off-road doing jumps and stunts ?   Have you ever serviced/cleaned the suspension?

Comment: Take it back to halfords. Sometimes on bikes in this price bracket, components used in assembly don't actually exist in the real world

Answer (score 3):

If it's only 6 months old, take it back to the shop as it wasn't fit for sale.

Comment: Warranty does not cover overuse or improper use. It only covers defects in most countries. Such a cheap bike may have disclaimers about the terrain they should be used at.

Comment: In the UK and EU, a failure this early is covered by consumer protection law, not the warranty. If it was sold as a mountainbike it needs to tolerate reasonable use.

Comment: The intended use is defined by the manufacturer and heavy terrain is commonly forbidden for these kinds of bikes. Jumps are almost always forbidden. Also, according to the question, those 6 months have likely already passed.

Comment: The OP still hasn't specified what kind of use the bike has had. The significance of the 6 months is on the burden of proof. In the first 6 months the retailer has to prove it wasn't a manufacturing or design fault, after 6 months the purchaser has to prove the use was appropriate.

Comment: You are oversimplyfying ad absurdum. For any appliance of any kind can this protection can only be claimed if the product was used as intended by the manufacturer. If a bicycle that is not intended for jumping is destroyed in a jump on the very first day, it is not the fault of the manufacturer.

Comment: To illustrate these disclaimers in practice, see https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/64704/what-do-i-get-by-paying-more-for-a-bicycle/64709 *"All of these are marked as:

    Not suitable for XC, All Mountain, Enduro and BMX.
"*